# Terminate EC2 instance after AWS Batch is succeeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-batch

I am running a simple java HelloWorld program using docker container in AWS Batch. I have created a managed Compute Environment with following values

Minimum vCPUs 0

Desired vCPUs 0

Maximum vCPUs 256

Instance types optimal

On submitting the Job, the job is executed successfully i.e. the job is submitted to the queue, the scheduler provisions the ec2 instance ( with aws-ecs agent container and java helloworld container which is specified in Job Definition) and the job is successfully completed with the logs in CloudWatch Stream.

My issue is that after the job is succeeded the compute environment (ec2 instance) provisioned by scheduler still keeps on running instead of terminating.

Pls. suggest if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 2):

Your compute environment will terminate if it is idle near the end of an AWS Billing Hour.

Inside the [Compute Environment Parameters documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/compute_environment_parameters.html) for AWS Batch, there is a definition of **State**.  A compute environment is in the *Enabled* state and can accept jobs from the queue.  Once the compute environment is in *Disabled* and idle, toward the end of an AWS billing hour the compute environment is scaled in (which will terminate your EC2 instance).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It means that if the job is started in the 1st minute of billing hour and completed in the 2nd minute of billing hour the EC2 instance provisioned will be idle for next 58 mins until the job is submittted in queue and then the instance will be terminated?

Comment: How can we automate this? i.e. to terminate the instance as soon as the job is completed from the queue.

Comment: If your processing is going to be that small - I would suggest you look into writing an AWS lambda function and going with a serverless architecture.  Please take some time to research it at the following URL:   https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/

Comment: I agree for small jobs lambda is the best option but how about long jobs taking lesser time approx. 5+ mins, the EC2 instance provisioned will be idle until end of billing hour and then terminate? how do I automatically disable the compute environment after job execution is succeeded?

Comment: Check your region - it seems that if you are in the correct region, the AWS Batch will scale down in a Per Second resolution - see this announcement as of Oct 17 - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/10/announcing-accelerated-scale-down-of-aws-batch-managed-compute-environments/

Comment: If you can't run your batch in one of these regions - I would compare the cost of moving it to lambda and running for 5 minutes vs. cost of 1 billing hour.  If the lambda is cheaper, then migrate your solution to lambda.

Comment: Agreed, for programs running up to 5 mins lambda is the solutions. I have few functions that run approx 20 mins. I want to put those in AWS Batch and terminate the compute environment once the execution is completed.

Comment: For jobs running 5+ mins AWS ECS with Fargate is the solution. Just create an ECS Cluster and submit tasks with Fargate instead of EC2.

Answer (score 2):

> From Oct 5, 2017

AWS Batch evaluate compute resources more frequently and immediately scale down any idle instances when there are no more runnable jobs in your job queues.
So, your compute environment instance will be terminated immediately if it is idle.

[Announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/10/announcing-accelerated-scale-down-of-aws-batch-managed-compute-environments/)